# How to call an Android app's method remotely?

Tags: android, testing, sip, remote-access

I'm working on a project that improves Automation Test for Android's App. What I want to do is very "easy": I have this very simple SIP Client with a basic UI and developed just reading the API guides on the android developer website (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html) that receives and makes SIP calls.

I need to control remotely this app from my PC, connected at the same local network or the same wifi, by sending commands or similar (without interact with the phone) to the app itslef running normally on my phone.For a specific example I posted the method initiateCall() that calls *sipAddress*(in the app, sipAddress is taken from a Text Box), what I want to do is:

- Starting the app on my phone
- calling the method initiateCall() from my pc giving a sipAddress as a parameter (I must not use the UI from the app running, that's why I need to give the *sipAddress*)
- check if an outgoing call starts from the app running on my phone

I thought that the solution must be something  about web-services,but I don't have any better ideas and i don't know how to start and where to start solving this problem,that's why i need you help.

```
public void initiateCall() {
    try {
        SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
         // set up the listener for outgoing calls
            @Override
            public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
                call.startAudio();
                call.setSpeakerMode(true);
                updateStatus(call, 2);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                updateStatus("Call End");
            }
        };

        call = manager.makeAudioCall(me.getUriString(), sipAddress,
                listener, 30);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall",
                "Error when trying to close manager.", e);
        if (me != null) {
            try {
                manager.close(me.getUriString());
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                Log.i("WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall",
                        "Error when trying to close manager.", ee);
                ee.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (call != null) {
            call.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it REST API style. You would need to set up a minimalistic webserver.

If you access for example the url `phoneip/ctrl/makecall?number=yournumber` a serverside method us called if set up correctly. Then you can call you method and use the GET or POST variables as arguments.

You would have to look into Java Webserver Libraries/Frameworks. You can pick a lightweight one for that purpose. For example [this one](http://sparkjava.com).
You could then also add security features (authentification to protect it) quite easily.

Example with sparkjava

```
import static spark.Spark.*;

....

get("/ctrl/makecall", (request, response) -> {
      String phonenum =  request.queryParams("number"); //may not be accurate; you have to determine the GET variable called "number" in that case; you can rename it; see docs!!!
      //call your method with proper arguments
});
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for the quick answer! I think i know what you mean,but i don't understand "where" to set up this webserver : it's something inside the code of the app or external? I just can't imagine the overall logic view : from my pc I call the webserver and this one calls the app?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes inthat case the webserver is then part of the app. Its usually started with a few methods (only one for starting but ussually some for configuration). The library does most of the job for you. Your app then listens on the port you specified and also provides an answer if you specify it. Overall view: From you pc you call an url (access the web page) with a browser or wget, curl something like that. And then within the app the method for that page(which is usually mostly used for modifying the html output if the page) is called which then calls the desired method in the app.

Comment: Ok,thank you very much.I will take as more info as I can and try to follow this way!

Comment: You're welcome. I can give you hints in the process, but keep in mind that java isnt one of my strong languages.

Comment: Thanks for the example,if I will have important improvements i will write them here to help other people too!

Comment: Sorry but I have a problem : I read all the features of Sparkjava,but I still don't understand how to basically run my app as a server that listen a specific port.Sparkjava let me execute methods when a webpage is called (like the example code you posted) but how i configure my app and initialize it like a server while running on my phone? Is there any function of soarkjava that i missed?

Comment: Just add the lines in the example and `Port(8080);` for example, together with the get(.... to a funtion that is called when the app is starting that should initialize the webserver and everything. You probably have to add the sparkjava libraries to your project.

Comment: Yeah sorry i just read that it starts by default (ops!).Just last question : are we sure that sparkjava works with android app to? Because on their website they never talk about Android App but just for webapp in Java,maybe it's the same?

Comment: Well as im not an expert in android dev or java i cant assure you 100% but as far as i know its just some java libraries wHich will run where java runs.